# Why does my Finder window close when I eject an external drive?

Tags: macos, finder

Why does Finder window close when I eject an external drive sometimes?  It's still in the menu system, but no open window to toggle to.  I was not in any folder on said external drive, but in the `Documents` folder - I am not even in a folder on the external drive being ejected..

I don't want it to close

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Before ejecting drive click on any other drive and then press eject, window stays open,